# Trying to mock a DLL in a python wrapper unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, ctypes

## The Problem

I'm writing a wrapper for a DLL in python, as it gets more complex I'd like to have a few simple unittests that check if the parameters passed to the dll are well formed and some error checks I have work. As the DLL connects over network to an external resource and won't work without that, testing it can be cumbersome and I want to mock it.

Here is a small example that behaves just like my wrapper:

```py
from ctypes import c_void_p, c_int, c_char_p, WinDLL, byref

class prod:

    def do_something(self, some_string: str, some_int: int):
        self.my_dll.do_something(
            self.handle,
            c_char_p(some_string.encode("utf-8")),
            c_int(some_int),
        )

    def __init__(self, dll_path: str = "dll_name.dll"):
        self.my_dll = WinDLL(dll_path)
        a = self.my_dll.frob()
        print(a)
        # prepare handle creation
        create_handle = self.my_dll.create_connection
        create_handle.restype = c_void_p
        # actually create a connection handle
        self.handle = create_handle()
```

## What I've tried

After reading the docs I decided to use `MagicMock` to patch out the call to `WinDLL`, so I can replace the `my_dll` in the wrapper with a mocker. A small example test, which I created similar to https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#mocking-classes:

```py
import logging
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock, Mock

from prod import prod

class TestInit(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("prod.WinDLL")
    def test_init(self, mocker):
        mocker = MagicMock(name="my_mock_dll")
        instance = mocker.return_value
        instance.frob.return_value="asdf"
        pr = prod("./some/path")
        pr.do_something("asdf", 6)
        print(mocker.mock_calls)
        print(instance.mock_calls)
```

I would now expect the call to `self.my_dll.frob()` to return "asdf", however it now returns `<MagicMock name='WinDLL().frob()' id='46863080'>`, looks like something was not instantiated right?

Also, both `mock_calls` print empty lists, which I also did not expect. I would expect that on the `instance` mocker the methods `frob`, `create_connection` and `do_something` are called...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Problem:

the line `mocker = MagicMock(name="my_mock_dll")` replaced the mocker with a new one, which was not really patched into the actual class, and I got garbage output.